# How do I identify that an array has unique entries in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

I have an array of strings

```
users: ['user1', 'user2']
```

If I run a search looking for exactly ['user1', 'user2'] in that order, it will find that entry. However if they are back to front, the query returns nothing.

What's the best way to compare an input array against the list in the database to determine if it is a unique entry?

Comment: please have a look at this: [mongodb distinct](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/)

Answer (score 1):

You can identify an unique array in a collection, by below query.

```
db.getCollection('mycollection').find({users:  { $size: 2, $all: [ "user1" , "user2" ]  }})
```

**You need to mention the no. of elements in array you are checking, and check all elements in it by $all operator.**

Answer (score 0):

Using the aggregation framework with the **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** pipeline operator allows you to proccess the logical condition with the **[`$cond`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)** operator and uses the special operations **[`$$KEEP`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#keep)** to "keep" the document where the logical condition is true or **[`$$PRUNE`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#prune)** to "remove" the document where the condition was false.

This operation is similar to having a **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline that selects the fields in the collection and creates a new field that holds the result from the logical condition query and then a subsequent **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)**, except that **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** uses a single pipeline stage which is more efficient.

As for the logical condition, there are [Set Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#set-operators) that you can use since they allows expression that perform set operations on arrays, treating arrays as sets. Set expressions ignores the duplicate entries in each input array and the order of the elements, which is a suitable property in your case since you
want to disregard the order of the elements.

There are a couple of these operators that you can use to perform the logical condition, namely **[`$setIsSubset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/#exp._S_setIsSubset)** and **[`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference)**.

---

Consider the following examples which demonstrate the above concept:

**Populate Test Collection**

```
db.collection.insert([
    { users: ['user1', 'user2'] },
    { users: ['user1', 'user2', 'user2'] },
    { users: ['user1', 'user2', 'user3'] },
    { users: ['user1', 'user3'] },
])
```

**Example 1:** **[`$redact`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/)** with **[`$setEquals`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setEquals/#exp._S_setEquals)**

```
var arr = [ "user2", "user1" ];
db.collection.aggregate([
    { 
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": [
                { "$setEquals": [ "$users", arr ] },
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5804902900ce8cbd028523d1"),
    "users" : [ 
        "user1", 
        "user2"
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5804902900ce8cbd028523d2"),
    "users" : [ 
        "user1", 
        "user2", 
        "user2"
    ]
}
```

**Example 2:** **[`$redact`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/)** with **[`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference)**

```
var arr = [ "user2", "user1" ];
db.collection.aggregate([
    { 
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": [
                { 
                    "$eq": [
                        { "$setDifference": [ "$users", arr ] },
                        []
                    ]
                },
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5804902900ce8cbd028523d1"),
    "users" : [ 
        "user1", 
        "user2"
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5804902900ce8cbd028523d2"),
    "users" : [ 
        "user1", 
        "user2", 
        "user2"
    ]
}
```

---

Another approach, though only recommended when **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** is not available, would be to use the **[`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)** operator as:

```
db.collection.find({
    "$where": function() {
        var arr = ["user2", "user1"];
        return !(this.users.sort() > arr.sort() || this.users.sort() < arr.sort());
    }
})
```

However, bear in mind that this won't perfom very well since a query operation with the **[`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)** operator calls the JavaScript engine to evaluate Javascript code on every document and checks the condition for each.

This is very slow as MongoDB evaluates non-**[`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)** query operations before **[`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)** expressions and non-**[`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)** query statements may use an index.

It is advisable to combine with indexed queries if you can so that the query may be faster. However, it's recommended to use JavaScript expressions and the **[`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)** operator as a last resort when you can't structure the data in any other way, or when you are dealing with a small subset of data.